# highcharts Nested Grouping right side border missing

Tags: highcharts, grouping, groupchat

When I create a nested group chart, right side border not drawn if only one nested group

```
 example:
```

[jsfiddle.net/gmrpY/7](http://jsfiddle.net/gmrpY/7/)

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues/19) github ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set max range in X-axis to eliminate this problem

```
xAxis :{
    max:0.5,
},
```